# ASP.net - Name does not exist in the current context but yet can navigate to name/definition

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Had a good search for this but the suggestions don't seem to solve my issue.

So I have started at a new company as the onlt devloper and the previous created there web-site using ASP.net Web forms. I don't really have experiance in this area and will be converting the site to use .Net Core.

Any way, the problem.
I am finiding on certain aspx pages I get the `Name does not exist in the current context` error. Yet if I right click and select `Go To Definition` it takes me to the code behind.

Here is an example.

Top of page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Dashboard.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="MasterPageAnon.master" Inherits="Dashboard" %>
```

Control example

```
<asp:Label ID="lblColumn1" runat="server" 
     Text='<%# CreateColumn(1, 
           Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "num_d_orders")), 
           Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "num_s_orders")),               
           Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "num_late_backs")),
           0) %>' />
```

NOTE: I have removed aload of the properties from the above as there were many and I think you get the idea.

So the error is a syntax highlighted one in Visual Studio on `CreateColumn`
But, as I say, if I right click and select `Go To Definition` it takes me to this code.

```
protected string CreateColumn(int p_column,
                                int p_num_d_orders,
                                int p_num_s_orders,
                                int p_num_late_backs,
                                int p_holds)
{
     // Code
}
```

Once in the code behind, Visual Studio says there are 0 references.

I have checked the number of parameters match and the types.

EDIT:
So ignoring the above I started looking into other issue and I am no wondering it all stems from one place.

There is a GridView and none of the click events for LinkButtons are working. Also, not all of the GridView events are firing. For example, `OnRowDataBound` seems to work with a breakpoint but `OnRowCommand` does not work.

After a lot of googling I have tried the following.

- Removed the code behind for the events and get Visual Studio to
  AutoGenerate new ones.
- Tried EnableEventValidation to True and False
- Tried CausesValidation to True and False
- delete the code behind file and aspx file, created new ones and copied the code back in.

Comment: Odd.  I can do a simple reproduction of your code and get it working fine.  Obviously I have to DataBind() the lblColumn1, but it will work as intended.  This code is not inside some sort of table is it? Other than that, not really sure.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the markup at the very top of the aspx file (the page directive)? Should look kind of like this: `<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="Foo.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="MyNamespace.Foo" %>
`

Comment: @JohnWu added as requested

Comment: @JohnPete22 it is in site a GridView? so its GridView ->Columns->TemplateField->Label